# "git add ." adds ignored files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a gitignore file

```
~\.gitignore_global
```

with several patterns.
I added a directory to my source, and run

```
git add .
```

Then when I run

```
git status
```

it does show me that the old ignored files are still untracked, but the new files with the  ignored extensions would be committed?

this is my gitignore file:

```
*.obj 
*.cache
*.tlog
*.resources
*.pdb
*.bin
*.user
```

Why is it so and what can be done to automatically ignore all the files I want to ignore on this and subsequent commits.

=======================================================================

EDIT:

The problem solved by installing a SourceTree client, which managed all the ignore stuff for me :)

Answer (score 4):

If you add a new entry into your `gitignore` which was earlier tracked, the file remains tracked. You have to explicitly untrack it.

```
git rm --cached filename
```

Then, if you do `git add .`, you will not see the ignored files.

Comment: In that case, Dogbert's suggestion should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the global gitignore config in ~/.gitconfig

You can run this to do that automatically:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved by installing a SourceTree client, which managed all the ignore stuff for me :)

Made a commit in 2 minutes, including initial options.

I think from now on I stick to the client...